# how to pass tmux varible to external script for the status bar

Tags: shell, environment-variables, zsh, statusbar, tmux

I am using the default <#{pane_current_path}> to display the current working directory for the current pane used. However the result is a lengthy full directory path taking lot of space in the status bar.

What I wanted is to use a shell script or ruby script to cut it short and display a short path like starting from home directory or just the last two sub directories.

I am stuck with find a way to let the shell script to take #{pane_current_path} as a varible, see below:

```
set -g status-left "#[fg=blue][#S] #I:#P #(cm_tmux_status_pwd.rb #{pane_current_path})"
```

I tested this, obviously it's not working.

There are other ways to achieve this but it's buggy, like to setenv then showenv in external script, see below, it just can't sync very well.

> tmux showenv -g TMUX_PWD_$(tmux display -p "#D" | tr -d %)  | sed
>   's/^.*=//'

So, please can you suggest if what I am expecting is doable or not, anyway to manipulate #{pane_current_path} ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of passing an argument to a script, why not fetch what you need from the script itself?

You can use this:

```
tmux display-message -p -F "#{pane_current_path}"
```

That will get pane current path in the script or from outside tmux.

If you're going to use bash for the script, here's how you assign the pane current path value to a variable (btw. double quotes inside double quotes are okay):

`local current_path="$(tmux display-message -p -F "#{pane_current_path}")"`

Comment: btw, I am using a few of your awesome plugins.

Comment: Is it possible I can have a per pane based - pane name for an indication what that pane is for? I found no answer yet and seems tmux does not support pane name now. Is there another internal varible similar to #{pane_current_path} that I can use to manually setup this name myself via my script?

Comment: There is a `"#{pane_title}"` format variable.. I'm not sure if it can be set (or is it a readonly). Also from what I see, that variable is not displayed anywhere, but you can certainly fetch it for your needs. Hopefully that helps to investigate this further.